# Altering fields included in Rails' default JSON/XML serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-services

I'm writing a web service to return a user's details. In the controller, I simply `render :xml => user and return`. However, not all of the fields of my User model are being returned, and I don't see anything in my model that would indicate which fields to include or exclude.

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name
end
```

Example:

```
irb(main):003:0> @user = User.find(3)
=> #<User id: 3, email: "me@me.me", encrypted_password: <redacted>, reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 11, current_sign_in_at: "2011-08-24 22:50:44", last_sign_in_at: "2011-08-24 06:18:41", current_sign_in_ip: "1.2.3.4", last_sign_in_ip: "1.2.3.4", created_at: "2011-08-23 17:09:28", updated_at: "2011-08-26 04:01:01", controller: false, admin: false, chargify_customer_id: 1234, chargify_subscription_id: 1234, first_name: "Me", last_name: "Me", chargify_subscription_state: "active">
```

What my `render` is currently returning for that same user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <last-name>Me</last-name>
  <email>me@me.me</email>
  <first-name>Me</first-name>
</user>
```

At a minimum, I need to include the `id` field; overall, I'd like to understand better how you control what gets included and what doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialization happens in the `as_json/as_xml` methods. By default these methods serialize all of your models attributes into json/xml. However, devise hides certain attributes generated by its ActiveRecord extensions. That's why you don't get the password fields for example.

You can control which attributes get included in your xml by overriding the to_xml method in your user model.

```
  def as_xml(options = {})
    default_options = {
      :only => [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email]
    }
    xml_options = options.blank? ? default_options : options
    super xml_options
  end
```

You can also include custom methods of your model.

```
  def as_xml(options = {})
    default_options = {
      :only => [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email],
      :methods => [:some_custom_method]
    }
    xml_options = options.blank? ? default_options : options
    super xml_options
  end
```

You can read more about serialization here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html

Comment: Thanks. Placing as_xml in my model didn't work - it never got called (verified by adding debugging loggers). I have a feeling devise's as_xml override overrided my override. ;-) However, I added a to_api method to the model using an options hash as you suggested and calling self.to_xml directly, and it seems to work well.